# How can I add my html code on my Index.html in my TextEdit/ Mac. My content in the index.html doesn't allow me to do any editing

Tags: html

I created an html page with TextEdit on my mac saving it at an HTML file, however when I click on it in my browser and want to add some structure, h1,p1, etc. the page is an online html and doesn't allow me to change or add anything

I changed the rich text to plain text.

Comment: ? https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: use a code editor like [Visual Studio](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and open your `.html` in that to add tags.

Answer (score 0):

Open it again using your TextEdit. Don't just open and click it, open the file in the TextEdit or Open Using TextEdit. Cause once you save it as an html, Mac or windows open it as a website.